# Facebook api - posting to feed with large image

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, post

I've got my app posting to feeds fine with the following code

```
$post_url = '/'.$pageid.'/feed';
$msg_body = array(
     'access_token'  => $access_token,
    'message' => $message,
    'picture'=> $image,
    'link'=> $link,
    'name'=>$linktext 

);  

try {
    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
}
```

This works fine, but all my pictures are auto re-sized to tiny thumbnails, is there anyway I can have them display larger.